# How to prevent users insert the same data when the quantity of the data has reached its limit?

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, sqlyog

I'm using VB.net and SQL for my project. I give a situation for my problem:

Table Quantity

```
id    Pro_no    Quantity 
1      123          4
2      456          5
```

Table insertData

```
id    Pro_no     Quantity    Description    
1      123           2         broken
2      123           1       missing part
```

As you can see user has inserted `Pro_no` for `123` into the `insertData table`. Meaning that it has `1` more `Quantity` can be inserted. My problem is when there are 2 users OR user open the same data with 2 tabs, want to insert the data at the same time, one of them OR one of the tab will not successful to do it cause it has reached the limit.

SQL :

```
INSERT INTO insertData (Pro_no, Quantity,Description)
VALUES ('123','1','broken')
```

VB.net

```
    Protected Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
        If ErrorChecking() = True Then
            DataInsert()
            DisplayMessage("success", "Done", "Data Succesfully Inserted!")
            clearAll()
        End If
    End Sub
```

DataInsert() Function :

```
Private Function DataInsert() As Integer
        Using create As New clsQuantityProject_dal
            Dim obj As New clsQuantityProject_info
            With obj
                .Part_No = txtPartNo.Text
                .Description = txtDesc.Text
                .QTY = spinEditQTY.Text
            End With

            Dim strResult As Integer = create.QuantityDataInsert(obj)

        End Using
        Return 1
End Function
```

note: do tell me if you can't understand my question, I'll correct and explain it better

Comment: what is the `limit` that you are referring to ?

Comment: @Squirrel, The limit of `Quantity`. As you can see each `Pro_no` has its `Quantity`. `Pro_no = 123` has `4 Quantity` meaning user only can insert it until the max of quantity.

Comment: use trigger to control it

Comment: @Squirrel, ouh I see. However, can I use trigger in store procedures? I am still new in this.

Comment: trigger is not stored procedure. I suggest you do some research on trigger

Comment: I don't understand your question completely. Your code is too minimal. Please see  [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The following may be helpful:  [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8) - see "Returns".

Comment: Provide full of code for DataInsert() function, my suggestion , when u insert into table, u need to check how many quantity already inserted and compare with ur limit quantity.if quantity is less than equal to , then allow to insert otherwise show error msg as quantity is full.

Comment: @AravindAravind, thank you !  I did what you suggest to me and it works !